# Converting VHDL to Verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I am trying to convert the vhdl code below to verilog, and it is not working properly. I have already done most of it, but I think I may have converted the VHDL keyword `others` incorrectly. Could anyone please help?

### VHDL Code

```
entity debounce is
Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       i : in  STD_LOGIC;
       o : out  STD_LOGIC);
end debounce;

architecture Behavioral of debounce is
    signal c : unsigned(23 downto 0);
begin
   process(clk)
   begin
      if rising_edge(clk) then
         if i = '1' then
            if c = x"FFFFFF" then
               o <= '1';
            else
               o <= '0';
            end if;
            c <= c+1;
         else
            c <= (others => '0');   --LINE IN QUESTION
            o <= '0';
         end if;
      end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

### Verilog Code Updated with Toolic's Suggestions

```
module debounce(input clk, input i, output o); 
    reg unsigned [23:0] c;
    reg out_temp;

    always @(posedge clk)begin
        if(i == 1)begin
            if(c==24'hFFFFFF)begin
                out_temp <= 1'b1;           
            end
            else begin
                out_temp <= 1'b0;
            end
            c <= c+1'b1;
        end
        else begin
            c <= {24{1'b0}};
            out_temp <= 1'b0; 
        end
    end
    assign o = out_temp;
 endmodule
```

Comment: "Others" means "every bit in `c` not already specified", so it means a 24-bit wide vector of zeroes. (I have no idea how to specify that in Verilog, sorry).

Comment: here, you may just say `c = 0;`

Comment: @toolic I am using a working vhdl code to read data from a camera and display it on a monitor. Since I am using Vivado, I can use both VHDL and Verilog code in the same project. I am converting each VHDL module into Verilog one at a time and testing if it still works. Also should I use an initial block to initialize c to 0?

Comment: @toolic I have tried what you said and it still does not work. Do you have any other ideas? I have updated my code to show your changes.

Comment: You don't want that `initial` block. `initial` blocks are not synthesisable. `c` is not initialised in the VHDL, so (assuming the VHDL is working OK), it doesn't need to be initialised in the Verilog, either.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Thanks I will try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: When you say "see if it works", are you simulating? If not, it's a good idea to do so. Here is a simple testbench that compares the two versions:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "see if it works", are you simulating? If not, it's a good idea to do so. Here is a simple testbench that compares the two versions:

```
module debounceTest; 
    reg clk=1'b0;
    reg i=1'b1;
    reg error=1'b0;
    wire oVerilog, oVHDL;
    integer k;

    debounceVerilog UUTverilog (clk, i, oVerilog);

    debounceVHD UUTvhdl (clk, i, oVHDL);

    always
      #5 clk = ~clk;

    initial begin
    for (k=0; k<2**26; k=k+1) begin
      if ((k%(2**25))==0)
        i = ~i;
      #10;
      end
    $stop;
    end

    always @* begin
      #1;
      if (oVHDL!==oVerilog)
        error = 1'b1;
    end

 endmodule
```

(Actually, I reduced the size of the counters in the models and simulated for a shorter time - this took rather a long time to simulate).

Why not do this for all these blocks that you are translating from one language to the other?

Comment: I tried your test bench and it seems like my module is working correctly. The rest of my code currently consists of a few VHDL modules and a VHDL IP. Do you know what could be causing the whole project to not work in terms of not being able to retrieve and show an image from a camera.